# How to decrypt the key

Tags: c#, .net, javascript, asp.net, mysql

Using C#, JavaScript & mysql

In the database i have the column like sign,

```
sign
ONr3XHNaUuROnolZpGSsdI+/b3mfOuXnBW7bW7M7cEBqE1RljubGNyc3f1ilFB1qJC9RkeZgaYcWFF1Z7DbgdHES78AAFYIcGMg5kzQdjR0wr1EQgmW+Z4TfmdmMlwNzbsdCPn6s0Bmlxt5HJ893KLrBGYhIRQre2JVje6u85Qk=
cqz+/tEn2q2Hc7Cwa7bXGYY6K77v37bZOW2HMfSCdmwh/qoFyFCvWo8wH9JpUnHV5V5359ak1fy3/jkO/bIEDDQxkLNtm5VRoBEWKkEJN0jRdGv3UzLXse1hGKQo772xM7De76hcuLE1hUetUhRK75JWwxzqVSqFCC7QLjtLwBg=
```

Used RSA algroithm for encryption, i want to decrypt the sign column value, how to do that.

Need Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably should use [RSACryptoServiceProvider.ImportCspBlob Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.importcspblob.aspx) which gets as the parameter byte array with keys data. In your example you may be also should convert this Base64 string to Unicode string bytes (or any else encoding, I don't know which one was used):

```
string signBase64 = ReadSignFromDB();//here you get the value from DB
byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(signBase64);
//here you have created rsaCryptoServiceProvider;
rsaCryptoServiceProvider.ImportCspBlob(bytes);
```

Then you should use RSACryptoServiceProvider as described in [RSACryptoServiceProvider Class MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s575f7e2.aspx).